# method to find actually data deleted or not in database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, flash, codeigniter

Hi every is there any way to check whether data is actually deleted from database or not in codeigniter ?
i have a method to delete data from database in my model as

```
             $this->db->delete('product', array('category' => $id));
```

and i have set flash datain my controller
the data from database doesn't gets deleted but the flash message is shown.

I need to show flash data only on actual delete from database.

Comment: There must be some way to get the affected rows. If that is 0 nothing got deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefer this

in model for example called 'products'

```
function deleteProductBy( $id ) {
    $this->db->where( 'category', $id );
    $this->db->delete( 'product' );

    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' ) {return TRUE;}
    else {return FALSE;}

}
```

in controller

```
  if( $this->products->deleteProductBy($id) == false ){

   // fail message is sad
} 
else{
   // success message is happy
}
```

so have the delete method in the model just return true or false -- then in the controller you decide how you are going to show the results. then when something changes for how you show the results - the delete method in the model remains the same. and while i'm rambling my suggestion is to check for false condition first.

Comment: Upside down true and false. I think must change like this `if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') {return FALSE;}else {return TRUE;}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($this->db->delete('product', array('category' => $id))) // This will return TRUE if deleted and return FALSE if it couldn't delete the row.
```

If that doesn't work i'd suggest using something like this:

```
$this->db->delete('product', array('category' => $id));

if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) // affected_rows will return you the number of affected rows, so if you delete one it will return 1.
{
     // show flash message
}
```

Comment: According to the codeigniter user guide $this->db->affected_rows() works only for write function as insert or update. So this function always returns false for me.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the data in table, write a select query for that category id. If count is zero then there will be no record with that category id. else there will be some date with that id. i.e, Not deleted.

For example,

```
function deleterecord(){
$this->db->delete('product', array('category' => $id));
//return TRUE or redirect to controller.
}
//after the above executed call the below function.
function findrecord(){
$query = $this->db->get_where('product', array('category' => $id));
if($query -> num_rows() == 0){
$str ="There is no data";
return $str;
}
else{
$str ="There is data";
return $str;
}
}
```

You can print the function return value to find result.

Comment: Not very smart imo, because you're using a whole new query just to check if something got deleted..

Comment: After deleting the record you have to find whether the data is present or not. For that you must add the select query after deleting the query. So add additional function for select query. that should be called after the delete function.